# Generic entity list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of entities, lets say `[Entity]`. Each `Entity` has different capabilities, for example some can be drawn to screen, while others can emit sounds. All of them can be printed for debug information.

Given this, we might have three typeclasses: Show, Draw & Sound. One entity may be an instance of Show and Draw, while the other Show and Sound.

I'm trying to find what the type of `Entity` would be, given these constraints, and given that I'd like to traverse the list by capability, ex: find all entities that can be shown, or all entities that can play a sound.

I haven't been able to express this with haskell's type system so far, the only way seems to be by using a runtime check, essentially implementing my own constraints system.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could `Entity` just be a product type with fields of `IO ()` and `String`?

Comment: The problem would still be of identifying what the entity is capable of though. I could generalize it to `Entity (Maybe IO) (Maybe String)` etc but then I'm essentially having to include all capabilities in all entities and do the checks at runtime..

Comment: How about using something like this: `data Entity = forall a. (Draw a) => Draws a | forall a. (Sound a) => Snd a` ? You can then pattern match on `Draws` and `Snd` and do your appropriate actions there.

Comment: @Sibi so the problem with that is if I want an entity that fulfills (Draw a, Sound a) -- you could have `DrawAndSound a`, but then searching for anything that can Draw won't match it, it will only match `Draws`..

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? This kind of question is usually a hint that you're designing your solution with a language other than Haskell in mind. If you tell us a bit about what you're really trying to do, we may be able to suggest a more idiomatic approach.

Comment: It sounds like your main objection to `Entity (Maybe (IO ()) (Maybe String)`  (which is what I would recommend) is aesthetic. Of course you will have to do the checks at runtime, when else do you expect to do them?

Comment: @luqui, well, I was hoping I could also have something like type constraints, which wouldn't let entities without the required features  be passed to a function, like: `playAndDraw :: (Sound a, Draw a) => a -> IO ()` - but I see how that may not make sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would only recommend modeling using those typeclasses if you are going to use the typeclasses in a way other than constructing and using `Entity`s -- otherwise it is a waste of time and lines of code.  See [the existential typeclass (anti-)pattern](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

The way you describe `Entity` is as a collection of "features".  A record with fields for the features is a common and clean way to model this.  For the optional features, use `Maybe`:

```
data Entity = Entity {
    image :: Maybe Image,
    sound :: Maybe Sound,
    debug :: String
}
instance Show Entity where show = debug
```

(I am using semantically meaningful names like `Image` and `Sound`, you may substitute `IO ()` if you want to think imperatively for these.)

Remember that you can use HOFs here, so functional features are acceptable:

```
    converse :: Maybe (Question -> Answer)
```

A pattern that is often used for this problem is, instead of creating entities using `Entity { ... }`, have them specialize a default:

```
defaultEntity :: Entity
defaultEntity = Entity {
    image = Nothing,
    sound = Nothing,
    debug = "<Entity>"
}
```

Then define entities like so:

```
invisibleDog :: Entity
invisibleDog = defaultEntity {
    debug = "<Invisible Dog>",
    sound = Just (Sound.resource "woof.wav")
}
```

Now when you add a new feature, you only need to update `defaultEntity` and all other entities will inherit the default.

Comment: I think this is probably the simplest way for small amounts of "features" per entity.

Answer (score 3):

You won't have much luck trying to express the differences between `Entity` at the type level. At least, not if you want to store them in a homogenous `[]`. You're immediately constrained that all values of `Entity` must be indistinguishable by type.

I think a type class or existential typing is not necessary. I would suggest the following:

```
data Trait = Showable String | Drawable Image | Playable Sound
```

where `Image` and `Sound` are defined depending on how you plan to draw images/play sounds. Then `Entity` is a simple composable collection of these traits:

```
newtype Entity = Entity (Set Trait)
```

You can easily provide a `Monoid` instance for `Entity` to allow combinations of `Trait`. Then you can "traverse the list by capability" like this:

```
showables :: [Entity] -> [Entity]
showables = filter $ \(Entity es) -> any isShowable (Set.toList es)
    where isShowable (Showable _) = True
          isShowable _ = False
```

with similar functions for `Drawable` and `Playable`.

Does this solution satisfy all your criteria?

**EDIT:** luqui points out a few flaws with this model as is. They can be avoided with manual `Eq` and `Ord` instances.

```
instance Eq Trait where
    Showable _ == Showable _ = True
    Drawable _ == Drawable _ = True
    Playable _ == Playable _ = True
    _ == _ = False

instance Ord Trait where
   Showable _ <= _ = True
   _ <= Playable _ = True
   _ <= _ = False
```

Now it is impossible for there to be duplicate `Trait` in the `Set` and provides a workable `Ord` instance. This is stretching somewhat and may not be satisfactory for your use case.

Comment: This is not well-modeled, since now entities can have e.g. more than one `Drawable` in their set of traits. Moreover, `Traits` is unlikely to be a good instance of `Ord`, which is required for `Set`.

Comment: I tried something like this with a HashMap which worked ok, I didn't think of using Monoid to combine traits, that's a great idea. I'm going to go with luqui's solution for now, because it allows me to easily pattern match on the traits, but I think both are good solutions.